# User interaction with PHP via command line skipping an input

Tags: php, command-line-interface, stdin, fopen

I have 3 identical snippets which ask the user for an input via command line. The first query is asked to the user and the third but for some reason the 2nd snippet is not outputting properly although its identical code. Below is the output:

[image]

As you can see it skips `content 2` and runs straight to content 3. Any ideas what is going wrong?

As soon as I hit `y` for content 1 the code runs straight to `Would you like to print content 3`!

```
<?php

echo "\n\033[1;35m~~~~~~ CONTENT 1 ~~~~~~\033[0m\n\n";

echo "\033[1;37mWould you like to print content 1? (y/n) - ";
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$response = fgetc($stdin);
    if ($response == 'y') {
      echo "\033[0m";
      echo "Content 1 print success!";
    }

echo "\n\033[1;35m~~~~~~ CONTENT 2 ~~~~~~\033[0m\n\n"; 

echo "\033[1;37mWould you like to print content 2? (y/n) - ";
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$response = fgetc($stdin);
    if ($response == 'y') {
      echo "\033[0m";
      echo "Content 2 print success!";

    }

echo "\n\033[1;35m~~~~~~ CONTENT 3 ~~~~~~\033[0m\n\n"; 

echo "\033[1;37mWould you like to print content 3? (y/n) - ";
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$response = fgetc($stdin);
            if ($response == 'y') {
              echo "\033[0m";
              echo "Content 3 print success!\n";
            }
echo "\033[0m";

?>
```

Using the do / while suggestion it allows me to input 3 times but this time for content 2 and 3 the request to input is duplicated!

See here:

```
    <?

    echo "\n\033[1;35m~~~~~~ CONTENT 1 ~~~~~~\033[0m\n\n";

    do {
        echo "\033[1;37mWould you like to print content 1? (y/n) - ";
        $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

        $response = fgetc($stdin);
    } while (!in_array($response, ['y','n']));
    if ($response == 'y') {
      echo "\033[0m";
      echo "Content 1 print success!";
    }

    echo "\n\033[1;35m~~~~~~ CONTENT 2 ~~~~~~\033[0m\n\n";

    do {
        echo "\033[1;37mWould you like to print content 2? (y/n) - ";
        $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

        $response = fgetc($stdin);
    } while (!in_array($response, ['y','n']));
    if ($response == 'y') {
      echo "\033[0m";
      echo "Content 2 print success!";
    }

    echo "\n\033[1;35m~~~~~~ CONTENT 3 ~~~~~~\033[0m\n\n";

    do {
        echo "\033[1;37mWould you like to print content 3? (y/n) - ";
        $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

        $response = fgetc($stdin);
    } while (!in_array($response, ['y','n']));
    if ($response == 'y') {
      echo "\033[0m";
      echo "Content 3 print success!\n";
    }


    ?>
```

[image]

Could it because the input has some white space or its capturing a newline? Sorry I'm just blindly guessing to be honest...

----- UPDATE -----

I can get my code to work by putting an additional if statment in to force the echo to print only once. Its a hack but if anyone can come up with a better solution please let me know!

```
    echo "\n\033[1;35m~~~~~~ CONTENT 3 ~~~~~~\n\n";
    $x = "1";
    do {
        if ($x==1){
          echo "\033[1;37mWould you like to print content 2? (y/n) - \033[0m\n";
          $x = $x+1;

        }
        $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

        $response = fgetc($stdin);
    } while (!in_array($response, ['y','n']));
    if ($response == 'y') {
      echo "\033[0m";
      echo "Content 3 print success!\n";
    }
```

Comment: The code works on my machine. You probably didn't enter `y` without any additional characters or nothing at all :)

Comment: hmmmm after inputting y for content 1 the question goes straight to content 3 so I dont get a chance to input for content 2 :(

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: PHP version: 5.6.99

Answer (score 1):

Your code works here. Anyway, if you want to get valid inputs, use this `do/while`, to just accept Y or N as input:

```
echo "\n\033[1;35m~~~~~~ CONTENT 1 ~~~~~~\033[0m\n\n";

do {
    echo "\033[1;37mWould you like to print content 1? (y/n) - ";
    $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

    $response = fgetc($stdin);
} while (!in_array($response, ['y','n']));
if ($response == 'y') {
  echo "\033[0m";
  echo "Content 1 print success!";
}
```

Comment: Please see my update above. For some reason its now duplicating my request for an input...

Comment: Done. Please check. Appreciated!

Comment: I don't have any problem here. Tested both on windows command prompt and linux. On which tool are you running this code?

Comment: My set up is Mac latest OS with iterm2!

Comment: This is probably a different behavior of PHP in MacOS and Windows/Linux. `fgetc` function. Try to prepend a `\n` before `echo "\n\033[1;37mWould you like to print content 2? (y/n) - ";` and/or with `\r\n`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128876/discussion-between-neverphased-and-felippe-duarte).